# "Stick" UIView and SCNNode together for animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nodes, scenekit

**Background**

I want to move a SCNNode and a UIView containing an image synchronously. The UIView with the UIImageView are positioned on the Node, so that it looks like they are the texture of the SCNNode (a cube).

**Code**

```
let move:Float = 15
let moveCube: SCNAction = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(cube.position.x-move, cube.position.y, cube.position.z), duration: 1)
```

**What I tried / How I do it right now**

I animate the UIView using:

```
var move:Float = 15
var projMove = scnView.projectPoint(SCNVector3(x: move, y: 0, z: 0)) //converts 3D coordSystem into 2D

UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: nil | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.myView.center.x = CGFloat(-projMove.x)
    }, completion: { finished in
})
```

This works, the cube moves to the left, the UIView as well. 
But this code is not really the best solution I think.

**Question(s)**

1. Is there a better way to let the cube move left, including the UIView?

   - Again, I want to move it both at the same time, best would be with one code segment
2. Can I possibly set one surface's (the front e.g.) texture to the image  instead?

   - I want to set the image as **only one side**'s texture
3. Could I even set the overall texture to an image and then put the image above it using it's alpha channel?

   - adding up to #2, I would like to set the cube's texture to a color and **above** that color I want to project the image (it has alpha layers so the color should still be viewable.)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to let the cube move left, including the UIView?

Yes. You can unproject the coordinates of the view and use this as a reference for the movement of the cube. See [Unproject Point](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/unprojectPoint:)

> Can I possibly set one surface's (the front e.g.) texture to the image instead?

Yes, simply set the diffuse channel of the material of the cube to your UIImage.

> Could I even set the overall texture to an image and then put the image above it using it's alpha channel?

Maybe, I am not quite sure what you are talking about, would you mind expanding on that? If I understand a little bit Spritekit would be your best bet.

Here are updated answers for the comments:

> I do use the unprojected points before projecting them in the SCNAction. And I meant more like moving both at once instead of a separate animation for each.

I don't think there is. You could animate a third party property and change its setter to change both the view and the node. You can also use blocks but in the end you cannot link the two directly.

> Well, I want to set the image only to one side of the cube.

You can simply provide an array of 6 materials, one being your image and the 5 other ones a second material to fill. You'll need to play with the order to find where the image needs to be in the array.

> That relates to #2, I want to set the texture to a color and then set one side's texture to the image I want to use.

There are two ways for this. You can use a shader that will add your image on top of a solid color, or you can make a second cube that is slightly smaller (less than 1%), and make that cube the background color you want. Then, use a transparency image on the larger one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To **#1:** I do use the unprojected points before projecting them in the `SCNAction`. And I meant more like moving both at once instead of a separate animation for each. To **#2:** Well, I want to set the image only to one side of the cube. To **#3:** That relates to #2, I want to set the texture to a color and then set one side's texture to the image I want to use.

Comment: (I did also update my post, thanks for pointing out that the questions were a bit unclear. Also, thanks for being polite!)

Comment: No problem! I updated the answer to address your new questions, let me know if it works for you.